# How do I debug EF in asp Net Zero

Tags: c#, entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

In a typical MCV project, for debuging Entity Framework I'd have something like

```
using (var context = new BlogContext())
{
    context.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
    //generated sql is now in output window
}
```

It looks like asp net zero is making my life easier by using a repository pattern. What is the new and improved way to get access to the raw sql that EF is running?

Comment: Put a breakpoint and debug. Nothing changed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging

Comment: http://rion.io/2016/10/19/accessing-entity-framework-core-queries-behind-the-scenes-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution;

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Abp.Domain.Repositories;
using Abp.EntityFramework.Repositories;

namespace AspNetZero.WebSite.Web.Controllers
{
    public class MyController : WebSiteControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IRepository<MyEntity> _myEntityRepository;

        public MyController(IRepository<MyEntity> myEntityRepository)
        {
            myEntityRepository.GetDbContext().Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```